# Can someone tell me if this sentence uses parenthetical expression?

Tags: grammar, parentheticals

When he returned as the day was ending, a little earlier than the previous day, I was expecting him.

Is "a little earlier than the previous day" parenthetical expression? 
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I explained why [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/257332/comma-to-set-off-two-verbs-phrases-with-different-prepositions/257359#257359)

Answer (score 1):

### Yes

In this case, the phrase **When he returned as the day was ending, I was expecting him** is interrupted by **a little earlier than the previous day**.

More information and examples on parenthetical expressions [can be viewed here.](http://www.grammar-once-and-for-all.com/punctuation/parenthetical-expressions/)

Comment: What is the specific rule for using it? Is it possible to just add any type of clauses or sentences in the middle of sentence if it does not change the meaning of sentence?

Comment: @Richard It would seem that yes, you can do it anywhere. That doesn't mean it will make a lot of sense to put it at a random point in the sentence. With appropriate context, it can be anywhere.

Comment: This is interesting. So if I say "He was crying, a sad scene, and it made me cry,too," it makes perfect sense?

Comment: @Richard Yes, because the **a sad scene** comes right after the scene, **He was crying**.

Comment: @Richard My brother thinks **He was crying, a sad scene, and it made me cry, too** sounds unintelligent, in case you wanted to know.

Comment: So the parenthetical expression can be just a word, or a fragment, or sentence,or clause?

Comment: @Richard It is a phrase or a clause, as the source described. If you want to know what being a phrase or clause entails... I guess that's another question all-together.

Comment: Another question has come up in the comments:  What works well in a parenthetical expression and what doesn't?  @Richard, I suggest you make a new question for that -- if you're still confused, after reading the link provided by Tkdestroyer2.

Comment: "He was crying, a sad scene, and it made me cry, too" -- I have to say, I'm with Richard's brother on this.